# How to give a self start event or alert in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to give an alert to user once the specific time has reached. The thing is, it should not be done in any of button click event or some thing. Even if the user is in some other page or some other website, alert should be displayed from my application. I am struggling to work with this theme. I knew with the page load or button click event, but i am blinking with this.

Comment: You say:Even if the user is in some other page or some other website, alert should be displayed from my application"... that can't be applied in a webpage ,Bec once you leave the webpage you. Can't do function on it, however it seems what you are looking for is the javascript function setInterval()

Answer (score 2):

Use settimeout\setinterval to make a js alert after X miliseconds:

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
```

This will alert after 3000ms(3 seconds).

[setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

[setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: It's fine. But I need to bind the alert message and timings from database. Can you suggest me any ideas for this condition ?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get you string from a server side function.

In your aspx file do something like this: var variable = '<%MyServerSideFunc%>';

and then add the set timeout message dynamically.

You can also perform an ajax call, get the message from a server function and then do the set timeout thing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got alert message from database by using this,
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg", "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> setTimeout (function () {alert('" + myDate + "')},3000);</script>");
But now i need to get time from database. I don't need 3000 i need to check the current time with my database column(time). If it satisfies it should give an alert from my application.

Comment: Then do the same you did with the "myDate" object. Javascript is a dynamic language. I thought about doing this a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on server side too:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.TimerCallback callback = new TimerCallback(AlertEvent);
        DateTime myDate=  mydate.AddHours(1);
        if (DateTime.Now < myDate)
        {
            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(callback, null, myDate- DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
        }

    }

    private void AlertEvent(object obj)
    {
        string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('THIS IS ALERT FROM C# TO JS');</script>";
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script);
    }
```